# How to categorize rows by SUM of a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as

```
id  num_items  folder
1   4
2   33
3   74
4   41
5   24
6   34
7   46
8   55
9   11
```

I want to assign folder number to rows but limiting the number of items in each folder (e.g. 100). Thus, increasing the folder number (next folder) if `SUM(num_items) > 100`.

The `UPDATE`d folder should look like

```
id  num_items  folder
1   4          1
2   33         1
3   74         2
4   41         3
5   24         3
6   34         3
7   46         4
8   55         4
9   11         5
```

Since, `SUM` make the calculation for the entire column, apparently, I need to reset the value/process of `SUM` after reaching the maximum item in folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option might be using user-variables:

```
SET @folder = 1;
SET @items = 0;
SELECT id, num_items, 
  (SELECT IF(((@items:=@items+num_items)>100), @folder:=@folder+1,   @folder)) as folder, 
  IF(@items>100,@items:=0,@items) as checkItems
FROM foo;
```

Here's an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/574ec/10) of it, though your example id=4 does not match. In the first block, it's 44, in the expected output block it is 41, so the folders are off.

---

Adding a caveat here. According to the [documentation on user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

Just keep that in mind.

#### Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA (2012-12-17 14:30 EDT)

So as to be sure of what the user variables look like, perhaps have each of the user variables printed along the way : ( [**See Example**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30479/877) )

```
SET @folder = 1;
SET @items = 0;
SELECT id, num_items, 
  @folder as CurrentFolder_Before,
  @items as CurrentItems_Before,
  (SELECT IF(((@items:=@items+num_items)>100), @folder:=@folder+1,   @folder)) as folder, 
  IF(@items>100,@items:=0,@items) as checkItems,
  @folder as CurrentFolder_After,
  @items as CurrentItems_After
FROM foo;
```

DTest gets a +1 for his application of user variables.

Comment: yes I was thinking of user-variable, but I wished not to use sub-query, as it is slow in long tables (which is my case). But it seems, I have no other choice!

Comment: Subqueries and being slow are not connected in any way.  Most probably you can speed them up if they are really slow.

Comment: Thanks for two versions, but please note that the question originally asked for `UPDATE` the table, rather than `SELECT`ing the data.

Comment: @dezso why subquery is not slow? subquery needs to conduct the process row by row. Am I wrong?

Comment: @All Have you tried it?